# Qt и staticMetaObject

Tags: c++, qt

При работе с `qt` с компилятором `mingw` столкнулся с такой проблемой: не мог создать коннекты с сигналами которые были определены в моей кастомной динамической библиотеке. После долгих танцев с бубном выяснил в чем проблема: я использовал `cmake` который автомат экспортирует и импортирует все из библиотек, НО! только не статические методы (и объекты)... В результате при обращению к `staticMetaObject` получал `nullptr` и сообщение о том, что такого сигнала нет. Но почему компилятор не сообщил о том, что у него `undefined reference` (как например это сделал `msvc`, проверено)?

PS более того, если использовать старый синтаксис для коннектов - то все работает...

PSS прошу прощения что сразу этого не сделал, подумал, что проблема мной описанно предельно ясно (ох уж это [проклятие знания](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

```
# cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(temp)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(LIB_SRC
  Alfa.cpp
  )

add_library(mylib SHARED ${LIB_SRC})
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC Qt5::Core)
set(PROJCT_SRC
  Beta.cpp
  main.cpp
  )

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJCT_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE mylib)


// Alfa.hpp

#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class Alfa : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ~Alfa() = default;
signals:
  void mySignal(int);

public slots:
  void mySlot(int);
};


// Alfa.cpp

#include "Alfa.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void Alfa::mySlot(int a) {
  std::cerr << a << std::endl;
}



// Beta.hpp

#pragma once
#include  "Alfa.hpp"

class Beta : public Alfa {
  public:
    void connecter();
};


// Beta.cpp

#include "Beta.hpp"

void Beta::connecter() {
  connect(this, &Beta::mySignal, this, &Beta::mySlot);
}


// main.cpp

#include "Beta.hpp"
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  Beta b;
  b.connecter();

  emit b.mySignal(42);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

На линуксе все работает (выводит ответ на извечный вопрос жизни, смерти и всего такого). Если компилить `mingw`, то при запуске выдаст:

```
QObject::connect: signal not found in Alfa
```

`msvc` вообще не скомпилит из-за ошибки:

```
unresolved external symbol "public:
  static struct QMetaObject const Alfa::staticMetaObject"
```

Comment: пока что мало-понятно, о чём вопрос... [mcve] в студию...

Comment: @Fat-Zer исправился: минимальнее некуда

Comment: пока разбирать не пробовал — под рукой нечем собрать, так что на вскидку хорошее решение не подскажу, но [`WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html#prop_tgt:WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS) явно оговаривается о том, что он не экспортирует глобальные данные, так что понятно, отчего ошибка… почему gcc пропускает, а msvc — нет? — вероятно там связывание устроено  по-другому, но это зарыто где-то в недрах Qt, так что на вскидку тоже не скажу… так или иначе ИМХО правильным практическим решением будет по-честному экспортировать всё самому…

Comment: @Fat-Zer это понятно, что нужно экспортировать все - я уже писал об этом, вопрос как раз и состоит в том, что почему mingw не выдает ошибку на этапе линковки?